# Why some people don't like proofs by contradiction

Tags: soft-question, meta-math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the “proofs by contradiction” weaker than other proofs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240/are-the-proofs-by-contradiction-weaker-than-other-proofs)

I have been active on this site for two months and on a few occasions I noticed that some people judge contradiction proofs as being less direct(and less elegant) than proofs which do not use contradiction.

In my first year of college I gave headaches to my seminar teacher and my colleagues because I used most of the time proof by contradiction. For me it seemed so natural to argue by contradiction whenever I didn't have any idea to how to proceed in solving the problem directly. At least when you prove something by contradiction, you have a start point, a supplementary hypothesis on which you can develop the following arguments searching for a contradiction with the hypothesis or previous work (theorems, problems, etc.).

Therefore, my question is:

> Why do some consider that contradiction proofs are not that good as direct proofs?

Comment: I don't think I can give a good answer; while you wait for one, you should see read on intuitionistic logic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic)

Comment: Did you see [this old thread here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240/are-the-proofs-by-contradiction-weaker-than-other-proofs)? Also look at the various threads in the linked/related column on the right.

Comment: Very briefly: A direct proof usually means that a specific example (or counterexample) is constructed. This is more concrete than an indirect existence proof. Moreover, a proof by contradiction usually relies on double negation elimination. This is not valid in intuitionistic logic, which is a weaker logic than classical logic. A proof which is valid in a weaker logic is sometimes more prized because it can be applied in more contexts.

Comment: Well G.H.Hardy won't agree with you: “Reductio ad absurdum, which Euclid loved so much, is one of a mathematician’s finest weapons. It is a far finer gambit than any chess gambit: a chess player may offer the sacrifice of a pawn or even a piece, but a mathematician offers the game ”.

Comment: If I could choose between having a constructive proof and a contradiction proof, I'd take the constructive proof any day.

Comment: A math TA once said to a friend of mine a proof by contradiction was not a real proof. I guess many mathematicans feel that way because they do not understand why it is indeed a sound proof method. After all, mathematicians seem (at least at my university) not to receive any formal logics education. @Zhen: often what is claimed to be a "direct proof" has been obtained by guessing a solution and proving it correct. While valid, I feel this approach lacks the inherent elegance a contradiction proof usually exhibits.

Comment: Also, the direct proof is regularly contrived or needs a lot of lemmas while a contradiction proof gives you all you need by assumption.

Comment: Two separate questions:  Proof of **nonexistence** by contradiction is fine.  But proof of **existence** by contradiction is less satisfactory: instead one would like a construction of the item asserted to exist.

Comment: GEdgar: A proof of negative statement $p \to \bot$ by assuming $p$ and deriving absurdity isn't really proof by contradiction. See http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/

Comment: For example, this proof is OK even for intuitionists:  THEOREM. $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.   PROOF. Assume contrariwise $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Then...

Comment: @Chandru: Firstly, Hardy is wrong there (in *A Mathematician's Apology*) when he says that Euclid's proof was by contradiction (read all the answers at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30127/is-there-an-intuitionist-i-e-constructive-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-primes)), and secondly (as in my answer below) proof by contradiction may well be "one of a mathematician's finest weapons" (when proving), but it's not one of the finest devices of a good expositor.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Read §12 in Hardy again. I fail to see a *substantial difference* between Hardy's account of Euclid's argument and Øystein Ore's in the article by Hardy-Woodgold linked to in Bill's answer. In any case: I don't understand why people make such a fuss about such a minor point.

Comment: In order to prove A, let's assume not A.

[Insert 10-page argument here.]

Which of the assertions proved in the foregoing 10 pages are false because they were deduced from the (now proved false) assumption that not A?  Which are true but cannot be considered to have been validly proved because the proofs relied on the false assumption that not A?  And which were validly proved since their proofs did not rely on that assumption?  It can be hard to tell.  And if you saw an assertion proved along the way, you might think it's known to be true. 

Thus proofs by contradiction can be confusing.

Comment: @Theo: It's a minor point to you because you have experience unpacking proofs, but it does make a difference to many students. Hardy's version begins with "Let us suppose […] that $2,3,5,\dots,P$ is the complete series (so that $P$ is the largest prime)", while Euclid's proof shows that given *any* (finite) list of primes it can be extended with another prime: no false assumptions required. As the "substance" being discussed is whether it's a proof by contradiction or not, this is a substantial difference. :-) (One can get one from the other of course, but pedagogically they're not the same.)

Comment: @ShrevatsaR: Thank you very much for the clarifications. I think I see your point now.

Comment: I suspect that proof by contradiction is weak to category mistakes. Consider that I want to prove that $|x| = -1$. Then I assume the opposite, but this assumption is incongruent.

Comment: In many cases, the direct proof actually establishes a stronger result and then applies modus ponens. For example, a useful way to prove that some particular set $A$ does not belong to a class $\mathcal{S}$ is by proving that every member of $\mathcal{S}$ contains an element not in $A$. If I did the argument by contradiction, I would assume $A\in \mathcal{S}$ and then deduce that $A$ contains an element not in $A$, a contradiction. The stronger statement--that every set in $\mathcal{S}$ contains elements outside of $A$--is obscured.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I find it harder to read and proofread proofs by contradiction for the following reason: In an ordinary proof, one is trying to show $P \implies Q$. When I read it, I will have in my head a few examples of different things that obey $P$, and I'll check that each step in the proof is consistent with my examples. Hopefully, the last line of the proof will be "$Q$", and everything will work.

In a proof by contradiction, we start out assuming $P \wedge NOT(Q)$. If the theorem is true, there are no examples of things of things which obey $P$ and not $Q$, so I can't think of any examples.

Note that this problem does not arise in proofs which start out by assuming $NOT(Q)$ and deduce $NOT(P)$ at the end, since I can think of examples of things which obey $NOT(Q)$. I have taken to starting these proofs by writing "We establish the contrapositive, that $NOT(Q)$ implies $NOT(P)$" rather than my standard "This proof proceeds by contradiction. Assume...". My hope is that this will help my readers understand that there are still examples available for them to think about.

Comment: but if what you're going to prove is not constructive to begin with ie. a non-existence then a proof by contradiction will be easier to do. I mean it depends on what you are trying to prove - something "positive" (like an existence) or something "negative" (a non-existence)

Comment: +1, especially for good advice on mathematical writing.  At this point I have certainly put in thousands of hours of writing mathematics.  Before my first few thousand hours, I would often assume that I didn't have to say much about the logical structure of an argument.  In particular I would often start proofs by contradiction by "Proof: suppose not.  Then..." Just recently I noticed that I have become more formal about this: "Seeking a contradiction, we suppose..." You can't be too careful in setting things up (well, you could, I suppose, but I have never seen it...)

Comment: I also agree that if something is an argument by contrapositive, then you should phrase it that way and not as an argument by contradiction, as David has explained quite well.  In some recent notes I found myself writing things like $\lnot$ (iii) $\implies$ $\lnot$ (ii) when proving that (ii) implies (iii) by contrapositive.  I'm not sure whether this will stand the test of time...

Answer (score 10):

Philosophical issues aside, a point that's been left out: what's better when proving need not be what's better when writing down the proof.

You say *"For me it seemed so natural to argue by contradiction…"*, and you're right: yes, it *is* often easier when *proving* to argue by contradiction, but the version without contradiction is often easier to *read* (and therefore better to write).

When you're trying to prove $P \implies Q$, if you prove by contradiction, then you get to assume both $P$ and $\lnot Q$ before exploring their consequences, so in principle it's never worse than assuming $P$ alone: proving by contradiction never hurts. But *after* you've finished the proof, it's worth going over your proof and seeing if it can be written directly.

That is, the issue (stylistically speaking) is not so much with proof by contradiction *per se*, but with writing a proof in terms of contradiction when it's not necessary or helpful. ("Proof by unnecessary contradiction".) See e.g. [*Mathematical Writing*](http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf) (by Donald Knuth, Tracy Larrabee, and Paul M. Roberts) for this (emphasis added):

> The proof above actually commits another **sin against mathematical exposition**, namely the unnecessary use of proof by contradiction. It would have been better to use a direct proof…

Sometimes (often) the direct proof may be easier to read and more illuminating, and sometimes it may not. It is always worth considering both versions and choosing the one that's easier to read. You owe it to your readers to think carefully about how best to organise your proof.

Answer (score 5):

To take a simple example, supposed you wanted to prove that $9$ was a composite number.

You know from [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) that $a^p-a$ is divisible by $p$ if $p$ is prime, but $2^9-2 = 510$ is not divisible by $9$, implying by contradiction that $9$ is not prime.

This is a fully logical proof which (combined with the fact $9$ is not a unit) answers the question, but I personally would regard showing directly that $9 = 3 \times 3$ as being more informative.

Answer (score 5):

I should elaborate on what I mean by weaker logics being more applicable.

Most mathematicians *do* believe that the world of mathematics is governed by the laws of classical logic. But there are worlds within mathematics itself which are not: although we may study such a mathematical universe using a classical background, the internal laws may not be classical. You might be dismissive and say that non-classical logic do not show up in ‘real’ mathematics, but the fact is that they do, albeit in somewhat disguised form. I give three examples:

1. The Curry–Howard correspondence between the type theory of computation and intuitionistic logic. In essence, if you can prove a propositional formula in intuitionistic propositional calculus, then, we can interpret the proof as a computer program, and the logical formulae as type declarations for the program; conversely, if you have a computer program, then its type declarations can be interpreted as logical formulae, and the program itself is a proof.
2. The algebra of open sets in a topological space forms a complete Heyting algebra: in particular, it is a model of intuitionistic propositional logic. A particularly memorable application of this is Kuratowski's closure–complement problem: indeed, if we denote by $\lnot A$ the interior of the complement of an open subset $A$ of a topological space $X$, then the fact that $\lnot \lnot \lnot A = \lnot A$ is nothing more than a special case of the general fact that $\lnot \lnot \lnot p$ and $\lnot p$ are equivalent in intuitionistic logic.
3. Generalising the previous example, a remarkable discovery of the mid-20th century showed that much of mathematics is interpretable in the categories of sheaves on a topological space. Such categories are known as toposes. The category of sets is, of course, a topos, but it just one of many. The theory of rings can be interpreted in any topos (or, indeed, any category with a terminal object and finite products), and such an interpretation is known as a ring object. A ring object in the category of sets is just a ring as we know it, and a ring object in the category of topological spaces is a topological ring, and so on.

   What about a ring object in a category of sheaves? Well, there, a ring object is the same thing as a sheaf of rings. This means that we can treat, say, the structure sheaf of a scheme as essentially the same thing as an exotic ring, and anything we can prove about rings will also be true of the sheaf, interpreted appropriately. With one catch: the proofs must be intuitionistically valid, because the [internal logic](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/internal+logic) of a topos is in general intuitionstic. (The internal logic of more general categories are even less pleasant.) In particular, double negation elimination is invalid, so any theorems proven by contradiction become suspect (but not necessarily untrue).

Answer (score 0):

I believe some people do not like proof by contradiction because it does not, typically, seem to lead to new mathematics or new ideas.  This is a rather general statement, but I think many will concur.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I agree with this.  Can you give an example of a theorem that was first proved by contradiction and then stagnated until a more direct / constructive proof was found?  (I certainly agree that if you don't know how to prove a result directly and someone else does, then she has some new idea that you don't.  But I don't think this is what you're claiming.)

Answer (score -1):

To prove something is impossible, you probably can't have a constructive proof and it's ease to understand the counterproof: You just assume that it's possible and derive a contradiction and you're done. Any other way to prove an impossibility?

Comment: Is this an answer to the question, or a question questioning the question? It should be left as a comment, I think. Anyway, proof by negation is not the same as proof by contradiction; see e.g. http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/

Comment: OK. Trying to answer the question more I say that a constructive proof can be more compelling to people since it's more straightforward, but at the same time it seems like there is no way to prove an impossibility using modus ponens: To prove an impossibility the way to prove looks like proof by contradiction

Comment: Did you actually read the above link? To prove an impossibility, what you usually use is proof by negation, which is **not** proof by contradiction!

Comment: I've never heard of that difference knowing the difference between inducative prrofs and counterexamples this was a third method I'm going to check

Comment: I looked at what you call proving negation and its still reducio ad absurdum so its true that both methods are the same: reducio ad absurdum using counterexample.