# How to find the closed form to the fibonacci numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove this formula for the Fibonacci Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence)

How to find the closed form to the fibonacci numbers?

I have seen is possible calculate the fibonacci numbers without recursion, but, how can I find this formula? Where it come from?

Appreciate helps, thx.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio

Comment: It's on the Wikipedia page ^^. What search did you employ that failed to show you this?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html) is probably the most expiated discussion of $n$-th term of Fibonacci series in world wide web.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by an "expiated discussion". IMO the linked page leaves much to be desired.