# Fibonacci sequence - how to prove $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} ((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n)$ without induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

How to prove that

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} ((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n)$$

without using induction?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula#Alternative_Proof

Comment: Generating functions can prove this identity, see [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/BinetFormula.shtml) for example.

Comment: This is given as a warmup in the free text by Wilf called generatingfunctionology.

Comment: why all of this downvote ?! I ask about something I have no information about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove this formula for the Fibonacci Sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: The reason offered for closure is nonsense thrice over. (1) **Questions** are incapable of seeking anything. (2) The apparently automatic assumption that someone who asks a ‘naked’ question like this is merely demanding a solution is ungenerous in the extreme. (And no, calling it _on hold_ rather than _closed_ makes the assumption no less insulting.) (3) Whatever the faults of the question, it certainly isn’t off-topic. The only reason that I’m not voting to reopen this is that (a) it has an accepted answer, and (b) it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generating functions. Let $F_n$ be the Fibbonacci sequence defined as $$F_0=1\\F_1=1\\F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\;\; ;\; n\geq 2$$

Let $$F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}F_nx^n$$ be its generating function. Then $$(1 - x - {x^2})F(x) = \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{F_n}} {x^n} - \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{F_n}} {x^{n + 1}} - \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{F_n}} {x^{n + 2}}$$
$$(1-x-x^2)F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}F_nx^n-\sum_{n\geq 1}F_{n-1}x^{n}-\sum_{n\geq 2}F_{n-2}x^{n}$$ $$(1 - x - {x^2})F(x) = {F_0} + {F_1}x - {F_0}x + \sum\limits_{n \geq 2} {\left( {{F_n} - {F_{n - 1}} - {F_{n - 2}}} \right)} {x^n}$$

And by the recursion the left hand side is $1+1-1+0$ so $$(1 - x - {x^2})F(x) = 1$$ $$F(x) = \frac{1}{{1 - x - {x^2}}}$$

Now use that $${x^2} + x - 1 = \left( {x+ \varphi } \right)\left( {x-{\varphi ^{ - 1}}} \right)$$ and the geometric expansion $$\frac{1}{{a - x}} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{a^{1 - k}}{x^k}} $$ plus simple fractions to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As $$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$$

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving),  $r^2-r-1=0\implies r=\frac{1\pm \sqrt 5}2$

So, $a_n=A\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}2\right)^n+B\left(\frac{1- \sqrt 5}2\right)^n$

where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants to be determined from the initial values $a_0=0,a_1=1$

Comment: Only the OP can say whether this counts as "without use induction" or not.

Comment: @GEdgar, not sure how the method is related to induction. But, the solution of recurrence relation gives the iterative version of a sequence.

Comment: Ruling out induction seems a peculiar requirement.  For example, if we know $a_n=A\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}2\right)^n+B\left(\frac{1- \sqrt 5}2\right)^n$ for $n=0$ and $n=1$, we want to conclude it also holds for other $n$...

Comment: @GEdgar, I think the recurrence method says $a_n=A\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}2\right)^n+B\left(\frac{1- \sqrt 5}2\right)^n$ is true for all integer $n\ge 0$ as $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$ is true for all integer $n\ge 0$ . Then we can put any convenient values of $n$ to determine $A,B$