# Using induction to prove a formula for the Fibonacci sequence involving the solutions of $x^2=x+1$

Tags: analysis, induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let $\{f(n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ denote the Fibonacci sequence defined by $f(1)=1, f(2)=1$, and $f(n)=f(n-1)+ f(n-2)$ for all $n\geq 3$.

Let $α=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $β=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$ Prove that $f(n)=\dfrac{α^n - β^n}{α-β}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So I'm using the Principle of Complete Induction for this problem but I'm slightly confused on the induction step. So for the base case I would should $f(1)=1$, which is true. For the induction step, would I fix $n$ at $3$? I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since the Fibonacci sequence is defined by the previous 2 terms, you should establish the base cases for $f(1)$ and $f(2)$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence

Answer (score 2):

The base hypothesis is

$$f_1=\frac{\alpha^{1}-\beta^{1}}{\alpha-\beta}=1,$$
$$f_2=\frac{\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}}{\alpha-\beta}=\alpha+\beta=1,$$
as the sum of the roots of the characteristic equation is the opposite of the coefficient of $x$.

Then by the induction hypothesis,

$$f_n+f_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{\alpha^{n}-\beta^{n}}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{(\alpha+1)\alpha^{n}-(\beta+1)\beta^{n}}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{\alpha^{n+2}-\beta^{n+2}}{\alpha-\beta}=f_{n+2},$$ as both roots are such that $x+1=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2=x+1 \\ x^3=x^2+x=2x+1 \\ x^4=x^3+x^2=3x+2$

...

Prove that $x^n=f(n)x+f(n-1)$:

Let $x^k = f(k)x+f(k-1)$. Then $x^{k+1} = f(k)x^2+f(k-1)x = f(k)(x+1)+f(k-1)x=f(k+1)x+f(k).$

Hence $(\alpha^n-\beta^n)/(\alpha-\beta)=(f(n)\alpha-f(n)\beta)/(\alpha-\beta)=f(n).$