# Limit of ratio of consecutive terms of a recurrence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

**My question is**:

> The sequence $a_n$ is defined by $$\sum_{r=1}^{k}p_ra_{n+r}=0,\forall n$$ where $p_r$ are fixed constants, and the "initial conditions" (i.e. the given values of $a_1,\ldots,a_{k}$). Let $\lambda_r,r\in\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$ be the $k$ roots of the characteristic equation $\sum_{r=1}^{k}p_r\lambda^{r}=0$. I want to prove that no matter what the "initial conditions" are, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lambda_r,\exists r.$$ Or this limit does not exist.

How to prove this? I believe it is true.

There are some more famous specific examples such as the Fibonacci sequence defined by $F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$. No matter what the values of $F_1, F_2$ are, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ can either be $-0.618$ or $1.618$ or **undefined**. I think it is related to the fact that $\varphi^n$ is the only geometric progression that satisfy  $F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$(yes there is another one, $(-\varphi^{-1})^n$).

So let's return to the general case. How can I decide which $\lambda_r$ will be the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ from the initial conditions? Is there a simple rule?

Comment: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000878/does-a-n-a-n-1-converge-to-the-golden-ratio-for-all-fibonacci-like-sequenc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true as stated.

For example, consider
$$
p_1=-1, p_2=0, p_3=1, k=3
$$
so $\lambda=\pm1$, and a solution
$$
a_n=
\begin{cases}
2 & n\text{ even}\\
1 & n\text{ odd}
\end{cases}.
$$
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\tag{1}$$
does not exist, so cannot be equal to either $1$ or $-1$.

---

**Addendum**: If the limit (1) exists, then it is one of the $\lambda_r$s.  This is because the general solution of $a_n$ is a sum of
$$
q_\lambda(n)\lambda^n
$$
where $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic (or auxiliary) polynomial $\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}p_{r+1}X^r$ and $q_\lambda$ is a polynomial (of degree one less than multiplicity of the root $\lambda$, in particular, is a constant if $\lambda$ is a simple root).  So dividing and taking limit:
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\sum_\lambda q_\lambda(n+1)\lambda^{n+1}}{\sum_\lambda q_\lambda(n)\lambda^n}\to\lambda_r
$$
where $r$ is chosen such that:

- all $\lambda_j$ with $\lvert\lambda_j\rvert>\lvert\lambda_r\rvert$ has $q_{\lambda_j}\equiv 0$, and
- all $\lambda_j$ with $\lvert\lambda_j\rvert=\lambda_r\rvert$ has $\deg q_{\lambda_j}<\deg q_{\lambda_r}$ (the degree of the zero polynomial is -1).

Comment: I have written that the limit can be "undefined" in my question. Please just consider the cases where limits exist.

Comment: Edited to expand on that case.