# Induction with Fibonacci Identity

Tags: induction

Using induction prove that: $$\sum_{i=0}^{2n} (-1)^iF_i = (F_{2n-1})-1$$

I am on the inductive step but am stuck with how to proceed.

This is what I have after the base case so far:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n+2} (-1)^iF_i = (F_{2n+2})-1$$
                              = $$(F_{2n+1})+F_{2n}-1$$
                              = $$(F_{2n-1})+F_{2n}+F_{2n}-1$$
I'm not sure how to simplify this out

Comment: What step are you stuck on?  All you have done is shown us the problem with no work.

Comment: You can also adapt this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1836559/589

Comment: The line $\sum_{i=0}^{2n+2}(-1)^iF_i=(F_{2n+2})-1$ is not proved when you wrote it.  Instead, you should build up to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch:
For $n=1$, the LHS becomes
$$
F_0-F_1+F_2=0-1+1=0
$$
and the RHS becomes
$$
F_1-1=1-1=0.
$$
Since the LHS and RHS are both zero, they are equal.

Now, assume that the claim is true for $n=k$.  Therefore
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{2k}(-1)^iF_i=F_{2k-1}-1.
$$
Consider the case where $n=k+1$.  In this case, the LHS is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{2(k+1)}(-1)^iF_i=F_{2k+2}-F_{2k+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{2k}(-1)^iF_i.
$$
Now, use the inductive hypothesis and break up your Fibonacci numbers.  Recall that your goal is to get that the RHS is $F_{2(k+1)-1}-1=F_{2k+1}-1$, so break things up to try to get towards that expression.

Comment: I'm confused with where the $F_{2k+1}$ came from

Comment: Look at the upper limits of the sums, the original sum goes from $i=0$ all the way to $i=2k$.  On the other hand, the bigger sum goes from $i=0$ all the way to $i=2(k+1)=2k+2$.  Therefore, the sum has *two* extra terms, when $i=2k+1$ and when $i=2k+2$.  To cut down the sum to the inductive case, you need to remove the first *two* terms.  $F_{2k+2}$ and $-F_{2k+1}$ are those two terms (after plugging in the two extra values for $i$).

Comment: When $n=3$, the sum is $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^iF_i=\sum_{i=0}^6(-1)^iF_i=(F_0-F_1+F_2-F_3+F_4-F_5+F_6)$.  On the other hand, when $n=4$, the sum is $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^iF_i=\sum_{i=0}^8(-1)^iF_i=(F_0-F_1+F_2-F_3+F_4-F_5+F_6-F_7+F_8)$.  Observe that the sum when $n=4$ has the *two* extra terms $F_8-F_7$.

Comment: A common mistake with sums is to forget that the upper limit matters.  A lot of times, people are so used to sums that have one extra term each time you increase $n$, they forget to look at the upper limit.  The upper limit in this case is a formula, so each time $n$ increases, you get two extra terms, not one.

Comment: So, removing the extra terms from the sum is a step you have to take any time you're doing induction involving these sums?

Comment: It is a common trick in induction involving sums, but it's not the only possible trick.

Comment: Ok I got it now. I just don't understand the exact way you get the two terms.I understand why they are there though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53723/discussion-between-janoycresva-and-michael-burr).