# Recurrences for even and odd indexed of Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I have a Recurrence:
$$a_{0}=1$$ $$  a_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)a_{k}$$
I have evaluated some a's:$a_{0}=1, a_{1}=1,a_{2}=3,a_{3}=8,a_{4}=21,a_{5}=55,...$. In the previous exercise on had to derive a generating Function for the even indexted Fibonacci Numbers. So these are definitely $F_{0}=1,F_{1}=1,F_{2}=3,F_{3}=8,F_{4}=21,...$

Then I had a detailed look on the summation:
$$a_{0}=1$$
$$a_{1}=(1-0)*1=1$$
$$a_{2}=(2-0)*a_{0}+(2-1)*a_{1}=2*1+1*1=3$$
$$a_{3}=(3-0)*a_{0}+(3-1)*a_{1}+(3-2)*a_{2}=3*1+2*1+1*3=8$$
$$a_{4}=(4-0)*a_{0}+(4-1)*a_{1}+(4-2)*a_{2}+(4-3)*a_{3}=4*1+3*1+2*3+1*8=21$$

Its obviously linked to: 
[Summation of Fibonacci numbers $F_n$ with $n$ odd vs. even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787341/summation-of-fibonacci-numbers-f-n-with-n-odd-vs-even)

But i dont see how to proceed.

Comment: Shouldn't it then be $a_0=0$?

Comment: its 1, i think it uses $F_0=1, and F_1=1$, might be a typo, but its says $a_0 =1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side is the convolution of sequences $\{n\}$ and $\{a_n\}$ (the term $0a_n$ is simply omitted). Taking the ordinary generating functions of both sides, we get
$$
A(x)-1=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}A(x),
$$
so that
$$
A(x)=\frac{(1-x)^2}{1-3x+x^2}=1+\frac{x}{1-3x+x^2},
$$
and thus
$$
a_n=F_{2n}, \quad n\ge 1,
$$
where the sequence $\{F_n\}$ starts with $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$.

Comment: I dont untderstand the -1? the right side has an index shift with +1 right?

Comment: @thetha No, there is no shift since $(n-k)+k=n$, not $n-1$. There is simply a missing summand of $0a_n$ on the right that extends the sum to $k=n$. Since it doesn’t contribute anything, nothing is subtracted on the right in the functional equation. The $-1$ on the left is there because the convolution on the right has $0$th term equal to $0$ whereas $a_0=1$.

Comment: Okey i think i dont get you solution. I know I have a sequence (1,2,3,4,5,6....) the generating Function for this one is $\sum_{n \ge 0}(n+1) z^n=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ When i multiplay this with x its a shift of the inder one to the right. Then i get $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

Comment: @thetha That’s equivalent to what I did.

Comment: Thank you for the Explantation