# Generating Function for even and odd Fibonacci Numbers, Missing Steps

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I am working through this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/787841/283262
and its connected to this one too: [Recurrences for even and odd indexed of Fibonacci Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806385/recurrences-for-even-and-odd-indexed-of-fibonacci-numbers)

I did not get all parts so I have added some parts, and the parts I did not get, maybe someone could ad the missing steps.

Definition of Fibonacci Numbers: 
$$
F_{n } = F_{n - 1} + F_{n-2} \qquad F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1
$$
The sequence :(0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,...)

One way to find the generating Function could be:
$$
F(x):=\sum_{n \ge 0}F_n x^n=_{since F_0=0}\sum_{n \ge 1}F_n x^n
$$
$$
F(x):= x + \sum_{n \ge 2}(F_{n-1}-F_{n-2}) x^n=x+x\sum_{n \ge 2}F_{n-1} x^{n-1}+x^2\sum_{n \ge 2}F_{n-2} x^{n-2}
$$
(Q1) One Question would be why this:
$$
F(x)=x+x*F(x)+x^2*F(x)
$$ 
My assumption is that since each of the sums converge towards F(x).

Now once could solve for F(x) and get:
$$
F(x)=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
$$

Then one would need to proove: 
$$
\frac{1}{2}(A(x)+A(-x))=\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{2 n} x^{2 n} and \frac{1}{2}(A(x)-A(-x))=\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{2 n + 1} x^{2 n + 1}
$$
With $ A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n$. This part is clear, open summation to even index and odd and the put it back together.

(Q2) I dont know where this is coming from? And how to prrove it.
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k \right) z^n
  = \frac{A(z)}{1 - z}
$$
(Q3) This part I dont get at all: why is $z^{1/2}$, and how to get the generating function:
So, for even Fibonacci numbers:
\begin{align}
F_e(z)
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{2 n} z^n \\
  &= \frac{F(z^{1/2}) + F(- z^{1/2})}{2} \\
  &= \frac{z}{1 - 3 z + z^2} \\
\end{align}

Maybe someone could add the missing steps. Thank you in advance.

update (Q2) solved. 
$$
F(x)=\frac{z}{1 - x} =1+z+z^2+...
$$
The coefficients are (1,1,1,1,...)
When multiplied with G(z) and apply the basic property of multiplcation for generating functions, you get this. Basic properties: Concrete Mathmatics p335

Comment: One question per post, please.  This question is too broad, and it is also off topic for lacking context (no effort shown on your part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Q1)** Here there's no need for analytic solutions, just manipulate the series algebraically changing indices. Since

$$
F(x) = x+\sum_{n \ge 2}(F_{n-1}-F_{n-2})X^n = X+X\sum_{n \ge 2}F_{n-1} X^{n-1}+X^2\sum_{n \ge 2}F_{n-2} X^{n-2}
$$

it suffices to note that

$$
\sum_{n \ge 2}F_{n-1} X^{n-1} = \sum_{n \ge 1}F_{n} X^{n} = \sum_{n \ge 0}F_{n} X^{n}
$$

and

$$
\sum_{n \ge 2}F_{n-2} X^{n-2} = \sum_{n \ge 0}F_{n} X^{n}
$$

If you stare at this long enough, you'll be convinced that in effect these are the same expressions. We're just changing the offset from the expression towards the index.

**(Q2)** Given two formal series $f(X) = \sum_{n \geq 1}c_nX^n$, $g(X) = \sum_{n\geq 1}d_nX^n$, their product is defined as

$$
fg(X) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\big(\sum_{k = 0}^na_kb_{n-k}\big)X^n
$$

if you take $A = f$ and $g = \sum_{n\geq 1}X^n$, we have

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k \right) X^n
  = A(X)\big(\sum_{n \geq 1}X^n\big)
$$

it suffices then to note that $\sum_{n \geq 1}X^n = (1-X)^{-1}$. To prove this, multiply the series by $(1-X)$ and conclude that their product is $1$ (once again, we only need algebraic manipulations of formal series).

**(Q3)** As you noted, summing $\frac{F(X) + F(-X)}{2}$ will cancel out odd exponents, leaving you with the series $\sum_{n \geq 1}F_{2n}X^{2n}$. However, you'd like to have $\sum_{n \geq 1}F_{2n}X^n$. From the previous expression, it's quite clear that composing by $X^{\frac{1}{2}}$ does the job. Since you have a closed expression for $F$ in terms of a rational function, you can calculate $\frac{F(X^{\frac{1}{2}}) + F(-X^{\frac{1}{2}})}{2}$ without dealing with series, which produces the aforementioned result, that is, $\frac{X}{1-3X+X^2}$.

Comment: Thank you! Is the $X^{1/2}$ like "folding" ? I have this rule: $$A(x^k)=(a_0,0,0,...0,a_1,0,...0,a_2,0,...0,a_3,0,...0)$$ where i have k-1 zeros in each 0's block. So since my exponent would 2n i could use  $X^{1/2}$

Comment: Edit: you've edited your comment, so I've changed my response accordingly :) You can think of it that way. Composing by $X^k$ spaces out the coefficients, whereas in the previous example composing by $X^{\frac{1}{2}}$ 'contracted' them.