# Recurrence Fibonacci Sequence Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

I'm having troubles proving that in a fibonacci sequence if n is divisible by four, then Fn is divisible by three

So when Fn is 6, n is 8 and so on. I was thinking maybe I could use mod 3 or mod 4 but don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: Try reducing the whole Fibonacci sequence modulo 3. You will see the pattern.

Comment: @Nocturne But how would I write that as a formal proof?

Comment: Try uisng induction on Fibonacci [mod 3]. $F_4=0$ will be the base case. Now, suppose $F_{4n}=0$ for $n \geq 1$ and prove that $F_{4(n+1)}=F_{4n+4}=0$. Just write $F_{4n+4}$ as a combination of $F_{4n+1}$ and $F_{4n}$ and use the fact that you count modulo 3 to prove that $F_{4n+4}=0$, i.e $F_{4n+4}=0$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: @Nocturne Thanks man! I'm just confused on how you write F4n+1 and F4n as a combination?

Comment: Just use the definition of the Fibonacci sequence down to $F_{4n}$ and $F_{4n+1}$. $F_{4n+4}=F_{4n+3}+F_{4n+2}=(F_{4n+2} +F_{4n+1}) + (F_{4n+1}+F_{4n})=((F_{4n+1}+F_{4n}) +F_{4n+1}) + (F_{4n+1}+F_{4n})=3F_{4n+1}+2F_{4n}$. Now, if you look the sequence modulo 3, the first term disappears because is multiplied by 3 and the second is zero by hypothesis, so $F_{4n+4}=F_{4(n+1)}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the matrix formulation, which is well worth knowing and [easily proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

We will prove by induction that $3$ divides $F_{4k}$.
Let
$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
$.
Then $A^{4(k+1)}=A^{4k}A^4$ :
$$
\begin{pmatrix}F_{4(k+1)+1}&F_{4(k+1)}\\F_{4(k+1)}&F_{4(k+1)-1}\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{4k+1}&F_{4k}\\F_{4k}&F_{4k-1}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}F_{5}&F_4\\F_4&F_{3}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so, by looking at position $2,1$,
$$
F_{4(k+1)}=F_{4k}F_{5}+F_{4k-1}F_4
$$
By induction, $F_4=3$ divides $F_{4k}$ and so $F_4=3$ divides $F_{4(k+1)}$.

Comment: More generally, if $m$ divides $n$ then $F_m$ divides $F_n$. Still more generally, $F_{\gcd(m,n)}=\gcd(F_m,F_n)$. Everything follows from the matrix formulation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just confused on this part "F4 = 3 divides F4k and so F4 = 3 divides F4(k+1)" From that equation, how do we know that 3 divids F4k and 3 divides F4(k+1)?