# Formula for fibonacci(a+b).

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Is there any general formula for fibonacci(A+B)?

I have tried to derive it , and got following results.
$$\begin{align}
&fib(a+1)=1*fib(a)+fib(a-1)\\
&fib(a+2)=2*fib(a)+fib(a-1)\\
&fib(a+3)=fib(a+2)+fib(a+1)=\!\text{(sum of above two formulas)}\!=3fib(a)+2fib(a-1)\\
&fib(a+4)=5fib(a)+3fib(a-1)\\
&\qquad\vdots\\
&fib(a+b)=fib(b+1)*fib(a)+fib(b)*fib(a-1)
\end{align}$$

Is this formula correct or there is something wrong..?

Comment: This is correct!  You may want to peruse Wikipedia's Fibonacci page, because they have this and more:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: this appears to be related to an active competition, https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ  .  I note that one of your prior questions was locked because it, too, was from a codechef competition (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686737/how-many-strings-possible-with-atmost-2-distance-away).

Comment: @lulu .! I am learning about properties of fibonacci numbers. Main motive of long contest is learning , you can learn lot of things . I didnot ask direct answer for that question . I just wanted to know that whatever i am doing is correct or not ...!

Comment: Your prior question was exactly equivalent to a (then active) codechef competition problem.  In neither case did you cite the contest as the source for your question.  Most people here would, I think, want to hold off on answering until the competition was done.  At a minimum, you should link to the ongoing contest so people can decide for themselves if they want to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the [matrix formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form), which is well worth knowing and [easily proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let
$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
$.
Then $A^{a+b}=A^{a}A^b$. Just read the corresponding entries.

Answer (score 2):

The $n$-th Fibonacci number is given in closed form by

$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n- \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n $$

You can see this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence)

So, the following can be proved by substituting the closed form formula in the R.H.S $$F_{a+b} = F_aF_{b-1} + F_{a+1}F_b $$
Let $x = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $y = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Then, $xy = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})(1-\sqrt{5})}{4} = -1 \implies xy + 1 = 0$

$F_aF_{b-1} + F_{a+1}F_b$ (in terms of $x$ and $y$) is:
$$ \frac{(x^a-y^a)(x^{b-1}-y^{b-1})}{\sqrt5 \cdot \sqrt 5} + \frac{(x^{a+1}-y^{a+1})(x^b-y^b)}{\sqrt5 \cdot \sqrt 5}$$
$$= \frac{x^{a+b-1} - x^ay^{b-1} - x^{b-1}y^a + y^{a+b-1} + x^{a+b+1} - x^{a+1}y^b - x^by^{a+1} + y^{a+b+1}}{5}$$
$$= \frac{x^{a+b}(x+x^{-1}) + y^{a+b}(y+y^{-1}) - x^ay^b(x+y^{-1}) - x^by^a(x^{-1}+y)}{5}$$
$$= \frac{x^{a+b}(x+x^{-1}) + y^{a+b}(y+y^{-1}) - x^ay^{b-1}(xy+1) - x^{b-1}y^a(xy+1)}{5}$$
$$= \frac{x^{a+b}(x+x^{-1}) + y^{a+b}(y+y^{-1})}{5}$$
$$= \frac{x^{a+b} - y^{a+b}}{\sqrt 5}$$
$$=F_{a+b}$$
because $$x + x^{-1} = \sqrt 5$$ $$y + y^{-1} = -\sqrt 5$$