# Finding a basis $\mathbb{R}_2$ of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a basis $\mathbb{R}_2$ of eigenvectors of $A$, $A =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 1 \\
    1       & 0
\end{bmatrix} $. Next, find the formula of $A^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have no idea how to solve first part of the problem. 
In the second part should I find $A^2$, $A^3$, $A^4$, try to guess $A^n$ and  try to prove my hypothesis?

Comment: The best way to solve this exercise is to diagonalize your matrix and then easily compute the powers of it.

Comment: The best way to solve this exercise is to first review the course material that led up to it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first find the eigenvalues. To find an eigenvalue, you want to solve the equation  $|\lambda I -A| =0$. This is called the characteristic polynomial, and in your case this polynomial is $\lambda^2-\lambda-1$. This has roots $\frac{1}{2}(1 \pm \sqrt{5})$. Then, solve the vector equation $(\lambda I - A)\textbf{v} = 0$ to get the eigenvectors. I'll let you take it from there. For the second part, I would do exactly what you said.

Comment: There is a very nice way to use part 1 in order to help solve part 2. If you elaborated on that, then this would become a _great_ answer. That being said, I haven't calculated $A^2, A^3, \ldots$ myself. There might be some easily discernible pattern even without resorting to using eigenvectors and eigenvalues, although it's not the approach I would recommend in general.

Comment: There is a rather pretty pattern that emerges if you calculate $A^2,A^3,A^4$, but you could also do this calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Solving $determinant(A-\lambda I)=0$ gives roots will imply that $\lambda=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. You then $rref(A-(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})I)=  \begin{bmatrix}
    1      &  -\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \\
    0       & 0
\end{bmatrix}$. Say $x_2=t$. Thus, $x_1=t(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})$.

Hence, $\begin{bmatrix}
    1      &  1 \\
    1       & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    t(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}) \\
    t
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    t(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})+t\\
    t(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})      
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
  t(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})\\
   t       
\end{bmatrix}$ (I know the last two matrices was a big jump; I'll leave that to you.)

Analgously to the first root, $rref(A-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})I)=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
 0 &   0 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Similarly, we figure (that being the hence part) $\begin{bmatrix}
    1      &  1 \\
    1       & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    t(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}) \\
    t
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}t\\
    t      
\end{bmatrix}$.

So find a $t$ that is not linearly dependent (zero would be bad) for this equation like $2$ and this will be your end result: $A^n=A(n,t)=\begin{bmatrix}
    t\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} & t\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
    t      & t
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n & 0\\
    0      & (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
   t(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}) & t(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})\\
    t      & t
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$.

I'll let you simplify  that nasty equation. Trust me the end answer is right though I checked. Also, $(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n$ is being raised to the power of $n$. I don't know why but it looks like I am multiplying it here for some weird reason.

Answer (score 0):

Because $A^2=A+I$, this matrix is the one expressing the Fibonacci recurrence: 
$$
{F_{n+1} \choose F_{n+1}}
=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}{F_{n} \choose F_{n-1}}
$$
This gives 
$$
{F_{n+1} \choose F_{n}}
=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n{F_{1} \choose F_{0}}
$$
and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
which can also be written $A^n= F_n A + F_{n-1}I$.

This [matrix formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) for the Fibonacci sequence is well worth knowing and [easily proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers).

By diagonalizing this matrix, we get [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet's_formula) for the Fibonacci numbers.