# Diagonalizable Matrix Intuition: $P^2=P$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $P$ be a matrix. We say is diagonalizable matrix iff

> $\exists$ an invertible matrix $A$: $\exists$ a diagonal matrix $D$:  $A^{-1}PA=D$.

I recently asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891521/diagonalizable-matrix-gre-math-subject-test-question/2891531?noredirect=1#comment5972104_2891531) as to why the following proposition holds true:

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ Let $P$ be a $n\times n$ matrix.

> If $P^2=P$, then $P$ is diagonalizable.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I am trying to better understand this proposition (see below):

> $\textbf{Why}$ do we rewrite $v=v-Pv+Pv$? It strikes me as an obvious statement which holds true, but it is always rewritten for a particular reason. And $\textbf{what}$ is the general idea as to why eigenvalues are roots of the following expression, $Q(P):=P^2-P$? I thought the eigenvalues might have been associated with the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) the way things are set up, but I could be wrong.
>
> > Roots for $Q(P)$,
> >
> > $P^2-P=0\implies P(P-1)=0\implies 1 \text{ and } 0 \text{ are Eigenvalues}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

Comment: I did not know that it was a projection. How does it being projection explain the why and what part of the question? I did find that helpful though.

Comment: If $P$ is a projection then $I-P$ is the complementary projection (it is explained in the Wikipedia page). This at least clarifies why one makes $I-P$ appear. A little more thought also reveals why the eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: (I disagree with the downvote and the close vote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to give some more details as an answer.

From the relation $\,P^2=P$, you obtain that $\;P(I-P)=0$, so $\operatorname{Im}(I-P)\subset \ker P$, and conversely, you can check $\ker P\subset \operatorname{Im}(I-P)$. Thus   $\ker P=\operatorname{Im}(I-P)$, and if $P\ne I$, this image is non-zero so you have the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $0$.

Now $P^2-P$ corresponds to the polynomial $X^2-X$, which is the minimal polynomial of $P$ if $P\ne 0,I$. As the eigenvalues are the roots of the minimal polynomial, you know there are no other eigenvalue than $0$ and $1$.

Further, $\operatorname{Im}(P)=\ker(I-P)$ is clearly the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Why is $ker(P)\subseteq Im(I-P)$? I tried the following:
Let $y\in ker(P)$. So, $P(y)=\vec{0}$.  [Show $y\in Im(I-P)$. In other words, show $(I-P)z=y$ for some $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$. ] But then I am not sure how to show that knowing $P(I-P)=0_{n\times n}$.

Comment: @W.G. What is $(I-P)(y)$?

Comment: For the last point, just expand by distributivity: $P(I-P)=P-P^2=0$. For the inclusion of the kernel in the image, if $Pv=0$, you can write $v=v-Pv=(I-P)v$.

Comment: I think you meant $(I-P)z$. Using $(I-P)y$, I would say it's the [identity matrix minus $P$] multiplied by the matrix $y$.

Comment: @W.G. NO, I mean $y$.  $(I-P)(y)=y-P(y)=y$ since $y \in \ker(P)$. Since $y=(I-P)(y)$ you get that $y \in Im(I-P)$.

Comment: @N.S. Lol on the NO. I get exactly what you are saying. I appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be so that $P^2=P$. Let $z \in \mathbb R^n$. Define
$$z_1=P(z) \\
z_2=z-z_1$$

Then, 
$$P(z_1)=z_1=1 \cdot z_1 \\
P(z_2)=0=0\cdot z_1\\
z=z_1+z_2$$

This shows that each vector can be written as linear combination of eigenvectors for $P$. Deduce from here that, if $E_0,E_1$ are the eigenspaces, then 
$$\dim(E_1)+\dim(E_0)=n$$
and hence $P$ is diagonalizable.