# Sum of specific Fibonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

This is from [problem 20](https://resources.thiel.edu/mathproject/atps/PDF/Chapt02.PDF)

Is there a simplified expression for sum of Fibonacci numbers: $$F(a)+F(a+4)+F(a+8)+\ldots + F(a+4m)\;\;?$$
https://resources.thiel.edu/mathproject/atps/PDF/Chapt02.PDF It is problem 20. I am thinking that maybe I could cancel out certain terms, F(a)+F(a+8)=7F(a+4). But I don't know how to do nex

Comment: You should put your thoughts in the body of the question instead of the comments.

Comment: Maybe Binet's formula will give you a proper answer?

Comment: Since $F_{a+4k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^a\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4k}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^a\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4k}$, then you can add for $k=0$ to $k=m$ to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^a\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4(m+1)}-1}{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4}-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^a\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4(m+1)}-1}{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{4}-1}$

Comment: What is $F$? Linking is not enough, insert from the remote content so many which makes your question comprehensible even if the remote link disappears. It is a rule here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using my favorite Fibonacci technique.

The [matrix formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) for the Fibonacci sequence is well worth knowing and [easily proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let
$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
$ and let's compute
$$
S = A^a + A^{a+4} + \cdots + A^{a+4m}
= A^a(I+A^4+\cdots+A^{4m})
= A^a(A^{4m+4}-I)(A^4-I)^{-1}
$$ 
The sum we seek is the $(1,2)$ entry in $S$:
$$
S=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{a+1}&F_{a}\\F_{a}&F_{a-1}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}F_{4m+5}-1&F_{4m+4}\\F_{4m+4}&F_{4m+3}-1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Render

$F_n=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n}{\sqrt{5}}$

Then your series is the difference between two geometric series and can be summed accordingly.