# Show a direct product is not finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I was wandering if anyone could tell me how my proof looks and it makes since. Here is the following question: Consider the infinite direct product $H = \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times$ $...$. I want to show that it is not finitely generated.

Proof: Suppose $H$ is generated by finitely many elements $k$. Since each element in $H$ has order $2$, the group generated by these elements has order of at most $2^k$. This is a contradiction since $H$ has infinite order, and such a set could not generate $H$. Therefore, $H$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: It's unnecessary to phrase it as a proof by contradiction. You are just proving, directly, that every finitely generated subgroup is finite, so $H$ (being infinite) is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof seems that nothing wrong, but one point is missing.
You have to mention that $H$ is abelian when you deduce that generated group, say $\langle g_1, \cdots, g_k \rangle$, is of order at most $2^k$. There is no guarantee that $g_ig_j$ is of finite order in general.

Comment: Suppose $H$ is generated by finitely many elements $k$. Since each element in $H$ has order $2$, the group $<g_{1}, ... , g_{k}>$ generated by these elements has order of at most $2^k$. This is a contradiction since $H$ has infinite order, and such a set could not generate $H$. Therefore, $H$ is not finitely generated. How does this proof sound now?

Comment: Is something differ from original one? Think about dihedral group $D_n = \langle r, s \mid r^n = s^2 = (rs)^2 = 1 \rangle$ for example (though this may be not good enough example). This group also generated by involutions (elements of order 2) $rs, s$; and the order of generated group is $2n$. So $2n > 2^2$ if $n \geq 3$. This is the case I mentioned in the answer by and large. So you have to mention that $H$ is abelian in the proof.

Comment: If I mention that $H$ is abelian in the proof, will the proof be good then?

Comment: @MickSmith Absolutely. Though I prefer to show "Let $g_1, \cdots, g_k \in H$ and $K := \langle g_1, \cdots, g_k \rangle$ ...  $K$ has a finite order at most $2^k$, which implies $K \neq H$" to [avoid proof by contradiction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240/are-the-proofs-by-contradiction-weaker-than-other-proofs).