# Is my proof that there are infinite primes incorrect?

Tags: solution-verification, prime-numbers, divisibility

I know that there is a much simpler and quicker way to prove this, but I came up with this proof before finding that simpler solution. I personally can't find any error in my proof so I am posting it here just in case anyone does find an error.

My solution is a proof by contradiction.

Assume that there are not infinitely many primes, then there must be $n$ number of primes. We can list all primes as $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$.

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, all integers that are greater than $1$ can be expressed as either a prime itself or the product of two or more primes. So then there must be an integer greater than $1$, that is the product of all primes. We call this integer $a=p_1⋅p_2⋅ ... ⋅p_n$. There must exist another integer, $b$, where $b=a+1$. Since $a+1$ is an integer plus an integer, we can assume $b$ is an integer. Notably, $b$ is an integer greater than 1.

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $b$ is either a prime or the product of primes. If $b$ is the product of primes then an arbitrary prime $p_x$ must divide $b$. So now we have $p_x|b$. Since $a$ is the product of all primes, then $p_x|a$ as well. Since $p_x|b$ ,$p_x|a$, and $b>a$ then $p_x|(b-a)$. Recall $b=a+1$, then $b-a=1$. Since  $p_x|(b-a)$, then $p_x|1$. $1$ is only divisible by itself, so $p_x=1$ BUT $p_x$ is a prime, and $1$ is not a prime, so this is a contradiction. We got to this contradiction by assuming that $b$ is the product of primes, so $b$ must not be the product of primes but a prime itself.

However $b=a+1$, where $a=p_1⋅p_2⋅...⋅p_n$. $a$ is supposed to be the product of every single prime that exists. Since $b$ is a prime, then $b|a$. If $b|a$, then $(a+1)|a$, but $(a+1)>a$. An integer cannot be divisible by an integer greater than itself, so $b$ being prime causes the contradiction that $(a+1)|a$.

Therefore $b$ is neither prime nor the product of primes. Ultimately, $b$ cannot be considered an integer greater than $1$. But $a$ is an integer greater than 1 and $b=a+1$, so $b$ should be a integer greater than 1, but it isn't.  So, $a=p_1⋅p_2⋅...⋅p_n$ is not an integer greater than $1$. But according to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $a$ should be an integer greater than $1$ because it is the product of every single prime that exists.

So finally, $a$ is not the product of every single prime that exists. $a=p_1⋅p_2⋅...⋅p_n$ implies that all primes can be listed as $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ but   $a=p_1⋅p_2⋅...⋅p_n$ being the product of every single prime is not true. So all primes cannot be listed, THEREFORE there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: This is the standard argument.  Well, sometimes people use a factorial instead of the product of the primes, but I'd say it was more common to use the product of the primes.

Comment: You don't need to invoke the fundamental theorem to define the integer $a$.

Comment: This version of the standard proof seems to take a little more space than usual, but a priori that's not a bad thing.

Comment: +1.You have re-discovered Euclid's proof. Many people, after seeing his, have wondered "Would I have thought of that?"

Comment: BTW even without the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, for $1<x\in\Bbb N,$ let $f(x)$ be the least $y\in\Bbb N$ such that $1<y\le x$ and $y|x.$ Then $f(x)$ is a prime divisor of $x.$ So in your notation $f(b)$ is a prime unequal to any of $p_1,...,p_n.$ Otherwise $f(b)|a \land f(b)|b$, implying $2\le f(b)|(b-a)=1.$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is correct, but you don't need to use proof by contradiction. And if it is possible to not use proof by contradiction, then generally speaking it is best not to—see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240/are-the-proofs-by-contradiction-weaker-than-other-proofs). The proof presented by Euclid is conceptually simpler:

> Consider any finite set of primes $S=\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Let $x=p_1 \cdot \dots\cdot p_n$. Since every member of $S$ divides $x$, no member of $S$ divides $x+1$. If $x+1$ is prime, then $S$ does not contain every prime. If $x+1$ is composite, then $x+1$ is divisible by a prime that does not belong to $S$, and so again $S$ does not contain every prime. Hence, no finite set of primes contains every prime, and so the set of primes is infinite.

Comment: +!: well-done: proof by contradiction should be avoided when it can be avoided - sadly, many mathematicians do not understand that.

Comment: Wow this is a lot simpler than I thought ...

Comment: @question_haver: I'd like to congratulate you for coming up with a proof yourself, though! It is common for someone to come up with a correct proof, and then for that proof to be made more concise and better organised later down the road.