# Well ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ in ZF

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

I am solving a problem about a certain set $S$(which exists in ZF and ZFC) where I have to show that it is countable. I know that $|S|\le|\mathbb{R}|$ so I assume by way of contradiction that there is a bijection between them. I can then prove that $S$ is well ordered, lets say by some ordering $\prec$. I claim this is a contradiction because, say $f: \mathbb{R}\leftrightarrow S$ is a bijection, then $x<y\iff f(x)\prec f(y)$ is a well ordering of $\mathbb{R}$(where the LHS is the proposed well ordering of $\mathbb{R}$). Have I solved this problem in ZF, but not in ZFC?

Sidenote: I have been intentionally vague about $S$ because I just want to know if my conclusion is valid. There are tonnes of questions on here [e.g.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/is-there-a-known-well-ordering-of-the-reals), but they either go over my head or don't give a straight answer to my question above.

EDIT: Following the previous proof, suppose $S\lt|\mathbb{R}|$ but is still uncountable. The construction of $S$ does not require choice, so this would be a contradiction to the fact that the contiuum hypothesis is unprovable in ZF.

Comment: Proving that $S$ is not bijection with $\mathbb{R}$ does not prove that it is countable unless you are assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @EricWofsey Could you see my edit please? Is this what you meant by assuming the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: You are confusing truth and provability.  Your proposed argument is analogous to the following: we know that the axioms of a group are not enough to prove that a group is necessarily abelian.  Now, take an arbitrary group $G$.  Suppose it is abelian.  That would contradict the fact that we know we can't prove an arbitrary group must be abelian!  Therefore, our group must be nonabelian.  Since $G$ was arbitrary, we have "proved" that every group is nonabelian.

Comment: @EricWofsey Rookie error. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric: Post as answer, then.

Comment: If you SUPPOSE that $S$ is uncountable and $|S|<|\Bbb R|$ then you are assuming $\neg CH $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have definitely not solved the problem in ZF.

This is because there is no way in ZF to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is *not* well-ordered (assuming ZF is consistent). For if we could prove in ZF that $\mathbb{R}$ is not well-ordered, then we could disprove the axiom of choice in ZF and thus ZFC would be inconsistent.

Furthermore, even if you showed that $S$ is not in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$, that still would not show that $S$ is countable. You are implicitly relying on the continuum hypothesis, which states that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ not in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$ is countable. But the continuum hypothesis also cannot be proved in ZF (in fact, cannot be proved in ZFC).

As mentioned in the comments, you are confusing proof and truth. There are three possibilities:

1. In all models of ZF, $S$ is countable. In this case, you can prove $S$ is countable in ZF.
2. In all models of ZF, $S$ is not countable. In this case, you can prove $S$ is uncountable in ZF.
3. $S$ is countable in some models of ZF but not in others. In this case, you can neither prove nor disprove that $S$ is countable in ZF.

Note that if you can prove $S$ is (un)countable in ZF, that exact proof is also a proof that $S$ is (un)countable in ZFC. So it doesn't make any sense to "[solve] this problem in ZF, but not in ZFC".

Comment: Is there any hope in showing the problem itself is not provable in ZF? (I am still aware I haven't posted the problem)

Comment: @settheory It depends on the specifics of $S$. But I would probably try to either prove or disprove that $S$ is countable before worrying about proving independence, which is typically far more difficult than an ordinary proof and requires a different mindset.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark Saving says, you have not in fact proved the relevant claim. However, there is indeed a way we can leverage the fact that $\mathsf{ZF}\not\vdash$ "$\mathbb{R}$ can be well-ordered" to prove *something* - it's just that the thing(s) we get out of it are a bit more technical.

Specifically, suppose I have a *(definition of a)* set $S$ and $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that $(i)$ $\vert S\vert\le\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ and $(ii)$ $S$ can be well-ordered. Then $\vert S\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ is inconsistent (over $\mathsf{ZF}$) with "$\mathbb{R}$ cannot be well-ordered" - and so we have a proof of $\vert S\vert<\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ **in the theory** $\mathsf{ZF}$ + "$\mathbb{R}$ cannot be well-ordered." But note that this falls short of a $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof, or even a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof, of $\vert S\vert<\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$.

The most we can say about what $\mathsf{ZF}$ can prove about $\vert S\vert$ is the following: if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent in the first place, then $\mathsf{ZF}\not\vdash\vert S\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$. This is because if $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash\vert S\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ then per the above $\mathsf{ZF}$ + "$\mathbb{R}$ cannot be well-ordered" is inconsistent, but we know that this latter theory is consistent if $\mathsf{ZF}$ itself is. But again, this is far from a proof in $\mathsf{ZF}$ or even $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\vert S\vert<\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$.

---

That said, it is quite possible that your $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof that $S$ can be well-ordered (if in fact correct) can be modified to give a $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof that $\vert S\vert<\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$, so it's not worth abandoning without further consideration.

Comment: This was a very interesting read. On your final note that I could modify the proof to give a ZF proof that $|S|\lt|\mathbb{R}|$, would this not lead to the same dilemma? That is, in efforts to show $S$ is countable, I could show $|S|<|\mathbb{R}|$, but I would run in to the same problem with the continuum hypothesis that I did with "$\mathbb{R}$ cannot be well ordered".

Comment: @settheory It depends on the details of the proof. My point is that while the *result* doesn't get you what you ultimately want, the *argument you used* may be modifiable. Without knowing the argument I can't say more.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for being so vague, I wanted to check my conclusion without spoiling the problem for myself.