# What (and how many) pieces does the Banach-Tarski Paradox break a sphere into?

Tags: general-topology, paradoxes

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) says

> There exists a decomposition of the ball into a finite number of non-overlapping pieces which can then be put back together in a different way to yield two identical copies of the original ball.

So my question is, how many pieces is the ball broken into, and what are their shapes like?

Comment: Related. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9799/banach-tarski-paradox and http://www.math.hmc.edu/%7Esu/papers.dir/banachtarski.pdf

Comment: Stan Wagon's book http://works.bepress.com/stan_wagon/13/ or http://www.amazon.com/Banach-Tarski-Paradox-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications/dp/0521457041/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1336098991&sr=1-1 is excellent in describing this.

Comment: Downvoted for not noticing that the Wikipedia article, linked in the question, says it's five.

Comment: @MarkDominus: Indeed, I deserve it. I didn't happen to get that far in the article since it was kind of over my head >_< thanks.

Comment: You may also be interested on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/611747/462) on the number of pieces needed for more than two copies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the article to which you linked:

> In fact, there is a sharp result in this case, due to Robinson: doubling the ball can be accomplished with five pieces, and fewer than five pieces will not suffice.

A reference is given to R. M. Robinson, [*On the Decomposition of Spheres*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm34/fm34125.pdf), Fund. Math. 34:246–260.

It's impossible to describe the shapes of all of the pieces. Another quotation from the article:

> Unlike most theorems in geometry, this result depends in a critical way on the axiom of choice in set theory. This axiom allows for the construction of nonmeasurable sets, collections of points that do not have a volume in the ordinary sense and for their construction would require performing an uncountably infinite number of choices.

Very roughly speaking, the construction of such a decomposition requires the ability to make too many arbitrary choices for them to be describable in any concrete terms. There are models of set theory in which such choices *cannot* be made, and in which such decompositions do not exist. This applies to four of the pieces in the $5$-piece decomposition mentioned above; the fifth is a single point.

Comment: I thought one of the five pieces consisted of the single point at the center.

Comment: @Mark: That's definitely true of the decomposition that I've seen. If didn't actually mean that *every* piece had to be non-measurable; I hope that it's clearer now.

Comment: But at most one piece of five can be measurable ... regardless of the decomposition.