# Optimal number of pieces for Banach-Tarski decompositions of shapes other than balls

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, set-theory

The [Banach-Tarski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#Banach_and_Tarski_publication) states that any [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set) [subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\ge3$) with [nonempty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) are [equidecomposable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Equidecomposable.html) by means of a [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set) number of [disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) sets. The standard example, which may be [used](http://people.math.umass.edu/~weston/oldpapers/banach.pdf) to prove the theorem and the idea of whose proof is [fairly simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#A_sketch_of_the_proof), is the decomposition of a [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)) into two identical copies of the original ball. The proof I am familiar with uses $25$ pieces, but it has been [shown](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/140712/284973) that the optimal number of pieces is $5$. I have wondered how many pieces might be required for other similar decompositions; in particular how many pieces might be required for a decomposition of a [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube) into two cubes, but I cannot see an easy way of altering the ball case to consider a cube.

Thus I have the following question: Is the [optimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) number of pieces required for the decomposition of a cube into two identical copies of the cube known? Is there an easy way of modifying the result for the ball to answer this question, or does the loss of [spherical symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_symmetry#Spherical_symmetry) make the problem much harder? Are there any other non-trivial decompositions for which the optimal number of pieces is known?

Comment: I don't think that linking to Wikipedia articles on "cube", "optimization", "spherical symmetry", "disjoint sets", "finite set", "subset", "empty set" can prove useful for anyone having already a slight *idea* of what Banach-Tarski is about ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Fair point. I obviously got carried away with linking.

Comment: Nothing is known here. It is a really interesting problem.