# Weird function or not

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is $f\colon\emptyset \to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ a function where $\emptyset$ is the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, this is a function. In fact, $f = \emptyset,$ and $\emptyset$ is a function.

Comment: So f: ∅ → Y where Y is any set including the non empty set is always a function

Comment: @Namch96, it may help to read the accepted answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60365/what-is-the-set-theoretic-definition-of-a-function

Comment: A function $f:\emptyset\to A$ is the empty function. It is being described as $\{(x,y)\in \emptyset\times A:\ y=f(x),\text{ and }$f(x)=(-1)^{1/2}$ \}=\emptyset$. The only problem here is whether or not $(-1)^{1/2}$ is a valid symbol in your language.

Comment: Ahhh ok i understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it wasn't a function into the real numbers there was a witness to this fact. Is there?

Comment: It's a bad definition anyway, because $(-1)^{1/2}$ is undefined.

Comment: That's the point methinks.

Comment: The definition should be formalizable in some language; if the language is unspecified, the definition is ill posed.

Comment: It's a valid definition if you agree that the result should generally be $i$, the question remains whether there is a real number equal to this term. Lucky for us, we don't have to check!

Comment: I disagree: $(-1)^{1/2}$ is not defined anywhere unless you *precisely* state what branch of the square root you use. But the question is not really a mathematical one; it's simply a bad question. I'm not blaming @Namch96, of course, but whoever posed it to her/him.

Comment: Yes, I agree that there is some inherent ambiguity. But the nice thing about oblivious freshmen is that you can lie to their face and use what "they think they know and don't know it's wrong yet". Of course I rarely ever do it, but I also hate numerical examples.