# $M^{\mathbb{Z}}=M^{\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}\times M^{\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $M$ be some finite set. Do we then have that
>   $M^{\mathbb{Z}}=M^{\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}\times M^{\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}$?

Since $M^{\mathbb{Z}}=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}M_i$ with $M_i=M$ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, it should be possible to split this product, ie.
$$
M^{\mathbb{Z}}=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}M_i=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}M_i\times\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}M_i=M^{\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}\times M^{\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}.
$$

Or am I completely wrong and think too naively?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Then it should also be true that $(M^{Z_{\leq 0}}\times M^{Z_{>0}}\times Z)\cup (M^Z\times\left\{-\infty,+\infty\right\})=M^Z\times Z'$ with $Z'=Z\cup\left\{-\infty,+\infty\right\}$?

Comment: How exactly do you define $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}M_i$ and $M^{\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: @Crostul I would rather say that it is *almost* correct.

Comment: @drhab The definition I had in mind was is the following. For each $i\in I$, let $A_i$ be a set. Then $\prod_{i\in I}A_i:=\left\{a\colon I\to\cup_{i\in I}A_i: a(i)\in A_i\forall i\in I\right\}$. If the $A_i$ always is the same, write $A^{I}$ instead of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$.

Comment: But $A\times B$ is just a set of ordered pairs, right? An indexset $I$ lacks there. That inconsistency is causing trouble.

Comment: I am not sure I do understand what you mean.

Comment: In short: LHS is set of functions and RHS is set of ordered pairs. Then the sets are not the same (functions are *sets of ordered pairs*, but are usually not ordered pairs themselves).

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are sets then $A^B$ usually denotes the set of functions $B\to A$, and $A\times B:=\{\langle a,b\rangle\mid a\in A\wedge b\in B\}$.

In that context what you write in your title is not true.

However, there is  a canonical bijection $M^{\mathbb Z}\to M^{\mathbb Z_{\leq0}}\times M^{\mathbb Z_{>0}}$ prescribed by: $$f\mapsto\langle f\upharpoonleft\mathbb Z_{\leq0},f\upharpoonleft\mathbb Z_{>0}\rangle$$
Its inverse is the map prescribed by:$$\langle g,h\rangle\mapsto g\cup h$$

Comment: So maybe it is correct that there is an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes. The map described in my answer is a bijection, which is an isomorphism in the category of sets.

Comment: In the map you mean the restriction to $Z_{\leq 0}$ and $Z_{>0}$ right? The inverse function is not totally clear to me yet (the union).

Comment: Yes, restrictions. If $g:I\to A$ and $h:J\to A$ are functions and $I\cap J=\varnothing$ then $g\cup h$ is a function $I\cup J\to A$. Here $g$ and $h$ are sets of ordered pairs, and so is their union.

Comment: Ok. Why do you speak of ordered pairs? I think for example $g$ looks like $(g(1),g(2),g(3),...)$ with $g(1),g(2),...\in Z$.

Comment: Sorry but have to go now. I will come back later.

Comment: So I guess it is right to say, for example, that $(M^{\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}\times M^{\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\times\mathbb{Z})\cup (M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\left\{\pm\infty\right\})\simeq (M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{Z})\cup (M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\left\{\pm\infty\right\})$ since $M^{\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}\times M^{\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\simeq M^{\mathbb{Z}}$. Moreover, we should have the identity (really identity this time) $(M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{Z})\cup (M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\left\{\pm\infty\right\})=M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{Z}'$, where $\mathbb{Z}':=\mathbb{Z}\cup\left\{\pm\infty\right\}$. ?

Comment: Let $Q:=(M^{\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}}\times M^{\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\times\mathbb{Z})\cup (M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\left\{\pm\infty\right\})$ and $P:=M^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$. Now, equip $Q$ and $P$ with their associated product topologies $\mathcal{O}_Q$ and $\mathcal{O}_P$. Do we then have that $(Q,\mathcal{O}_Q)\simeq (P,\mathcal{O}_P)$, i.e.. both topological spaces are isomorphic? Maybe this is just via the bijection you have already defined in your answer, since I guess it is continuous with respect to the the product topologies as well as its inverse?

Comment: I speak of ordered pairs because a function is a special set of ordered pairs. See (the answers) on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/60365/75923). What you say in your comment starting with "So I guess.." is correct. In your last comment we are somehow drifting away from the original question which did not involve any topologies. But yes, my intuition tells me that the spaces will be isomorphic objects in the category of topological spaces also. It goes too far too handle this in a comment. If you want precision then a new question is needed equipped with the tag topology.

Answer (score 0):

Whether there is exact equality depends on exactly how you construct products and function spaces. In my book, $M^{\Bbb Z}$ and $\prod_{i\in \Bbb Z}M$ are not exactly the same. An element $f\in M^{\Bbb Z}$ is a set of ordered pairs
$$
f=\{\ldots,(-1,m_{-1}),(0,m_0),(1,m_1),\ldots\}
$$
with $m_i\in M$, while an element $x\in \prod_{i\in \Bbb Z}M$ is an ordered tuple
$$
x=(\ldots,m_{-1},m_0,m_1,\ldots).
$$
So the two sets aren't equal. Finally, the third set, $M^{\Bbb Z_{\leq 0}}\times M^{\Bbb Z_{>0}}$, consists of pairs of sets of pairs. In other words, an element $y$ looks like this:
$$
y=(\{\ldots,(-1,m_{-1}),(0,m_0)\},\{(1,m_1),(2,m_2),\ldots\})
$$
That being said, there are canonical bijections between all these sets.