# a function must have to consider about its domain and codomain?

Tags: general-topology, functions

From the book principle of mathematical analysis define 2.1:

> Consider two sets $A$ and $B$, whose elements may be any objects whatsoever, and suppose that with each element $x$ of $A$ there is associated, in some manner, an element of $B$, which we denote by $f(x)$. $f$ is said to be a function from A to B(or a mapping of A into B )

My understanding:
when we talk about a function, formally, we have to specify the domain $A$ and the codomain $B$.

Example:

1. the function $f(x)=2x$, with the domain A=[1,2] and codomain B=[2,4]
2. the function $f(x)=2x$, with the domain A=[1,2] and codomain B=[0,100].
3. Strictly, formally, that is two different functions, right?
4. Actually the former one is a surjective function, and the latter is not, right?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59432/domain-co-domain-range-of-a-function/59503#59503)  Basically, there are two ways of thinking about a function, leading to slightly different issues.

Comment: In your example, isn't $A$ the domain and $B$ the codomain? As for your examples, your assertions are correct.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To  a set theorist the examples are the same function. In set theory a function IS its graph (as set theorists want everything to be a set). With this definition, a function can be said to be injective/surjective/bijective from its domain to a *specified* co-domain.

Your example is surjective *to* $[2,4]$ but not *to* any other set.

Anther term is the image of a function $f$, which is  $\{y: \exists x\,(\,(x,y)\in f\}$. Note that "$\in f \,$" means "in the graph of $f $ ".

Comment: Concerning the set-theoretic concept of a function you are right - unfortunately ;-) I would prefer to define a function as triple $(X,Y,f)$, where $X,Y$ are sets and $f \subset X \times Y$ is a subset with suitable properties.

Comment: so, if we define a function as a triple $(X, Y, f)$, then $X$ is the domain, $Y$ is the image, and the $f$ is the rule? In this case, we don't care about the codomain that much, and think it as an additional thing of the function.

Comment: @dawen: No, generally in that formulation, $Y$ is the codomain, a set that *contains* (but need not be equal to) the image.

Comment: Don't use math mode for italics; math italic is different from regular italic, and hard to read. To get italics, use `*`: e.g., `writing *this* will produce *italics*, and two asterisks yields **boldface**` gives: writing *this* will produce *italics*, and two asterisks yields **boldface**.

Comment: OK, so, actually, the domain\codomain\image(which is implicitly in the $f$)\ everything is inside that triple formulation $(X, Y, f)$. And if we just consider the $f$, my example is actually the same function, but if we use the triple formulation, it is not the same function.

Comment: @PaulFrost . That is a logical alternative.

Comment: @dawen Yes, that is correct. They are inequivalent formulations, so you always need to be careful and pay attention to which formulation is being used in a particular text.