# $f\cap(A\times Y)$ is a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have the following exercise:

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function and $A\subset X$ is a set. It is true that $f\cap(A\times Y)$ is a function?

At first I thought this was the restriction function, but I checked the definition of the restriction of a function and it does not match this one. I thought that since f is a function, and $f \subset X\times Y$ then that was enough to see that $f\cap(A\times Y)$ is a function, but I think it is not enough, could you please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f\cap(A\times Y)$ is indeed a function:

- Its elements are elements of $X \times Y$.
- Each element is paired with just one element of $Y$.

However it is not a function from $X$ to $Y$. It is a function from $A$ to $Y$.

Comment: Thanks, when you mention "Each element is paired with only one element of ", how can you prove that? I think that would be enough to see what a function is, right?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what $f\cap(A\times Y)$ is defined as? It just looks like a set to me.

Comment: I think I understand what the idea is supposed to be but man that's confusing notation.

Comment: @DerekLuna Yes, it is a set. In set theory, functions are encoded as sets.

Comment: That's why I included the word "just". I know functions are sets. But not all sets are functions.

Comment: @DerekLuna And the subsequent three lines explain why the intersection of the set $f$ with the set $A\times Y$ is a function in the set-theoretic sense.

Comment: If you have an intersection of a function and a set, it is not exactly clear it's a function just because you list the two requirements for it to be one as bullet points. The confusing part was the *notation itself*. What about this is so hard for you to understand?

Comment: @Haus *"Each element is paired with only one element of "* because this is the case for $f$ itself as it is supposed to be a function. By making the intersection, all ordered pairs having the first element in $A$ will remain.

Comment: See also [What is the set-theoretic definition of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60365/what-is-the-set-theoretic-definition-of-a-function).