# Finite dimensional subspaces of a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Suppose $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space. I do not want to assume the axiom of choice, so I will define a vector space $V$ to be infinite dimensional if there is a proper subspace $W\subseteq V$ such that $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

My question: Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is there a subspace $U\subseteq V$ of dimension $n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even without the axiom of choice there is a sense to say that a vector space is finitely generated, i.e. has a finite dimension. It is just to say that there the vector space is a *finite* direct sum of copies of the field.

To say that a vector space has an infinite dimension, relies on the sense of dimension which indeed breaks down when the axiom of choice does not hold; however one can say that a vector space is *not of finite dimension*. Much like an infinite set is just a set which is not finite. This is a broader definition than the one you give, it is possible to have a vector space without a basis (thus not of finite dimension) that every proper subspace has a finite dimension. The following arguments works regardless:

Given a vector space which is not of finite dimension, we can choose $n$ which are linearly independent their span is $U$ that you seek. We prove that by induction:

For $n=1$ it is obvious. Take any nonzero vector in $V$.

Suppose that you chose $n$ vectors, call them $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. Since $V$ is not spanned by finitely many vectors the span of $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is not the entire space $V$, therefore we can take some $v\in V$ which is not in this span. Now we have $v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1}=v$. As wanted.

---

Note that the induction only holds for *finitely many vectors* and we cannot deduce that there are countably many linearly independent vectors. It would require *some* choice, namely **The Principle of Dependent Choice**. From this principle follows that if we define something inductively then we can find an infinite sequence with the property we want.

**Further reading material:**

1. [Finite choice without AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64237/finite-choice-without-ac)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Induction on $n$:

For $n=0$, take $U=\{\mathbf{0}\}$.

Assume the result is true for $k$. Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ of dimension $k$. Then $U\neq V$, because $U$ is not isomorphic to any proper subspace of $U$, but $V$ *does*. Therefore, there exists $v\in V-U$. Let $\beta$ be a basis for $U$ (which exists since we are assuming $U$ is of dimension $k$). Then $\beta\cup\{u\}$ is linearly independent, and spans $\mathrm{span}(U,v)$. So $\mathrm{span}(U,v)$ is of dimension $k+1$, proving that $V$ has a subspace of dimension $k+1$.

The choice of the single $v\in V-U$ does not require the Axiom of Choice, since $V-U$ is nonempty and this is a single choice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can sequentially find $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$ by the process of always picking something outside the span of the preceding ones. No finite set will generate all of $V$, because then the theory of f.d. vector spaces (where dimension can be defined without AC) prohibits the existence of $W$. Thus there will always be room for one more linearly independent vector.