# Proving that a vector space $\mathbb{R}^k, k\in \mathbb N$ has a basis with ZF (and no Axiom of Choice)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finite dimensional subspaces of a linear space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91222/finite-dimensional-subspaces-of-a-linear-space)

I know that "every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to the "Axiom of Choice".

> My question: Can I prove that $\mathbb{R}^k$ has a basis (where $k\in \mathbb{N}$) only with ZF? If so, how?

Comment: The result you want to ask about is that a _finitely-generated_ vector space (a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$) has a basis. The proof is very easy: pick a set of generators, and if they are not linearly independent discard one. Repeat. This requires no choice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I think "no choice" is stretching it -- after all you're _choosing_ a generator to discard. It's just that Finite Choice is a theorem of ZF.

Comment: Okay, sure. When I say "no choice" I mean "no use of the axiom of choice."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $\mathbb R^k$ you can exhibit a basis, namely the vectors $(1,0,0,0,\ldots,0), (0,1,0,0,\ldots,0), (0,0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots ,(0,0,0,0,\ldots,1)$.

Comment: You're right.. More precisely, i just proved it by induction thanks