# Inverse of a set, possible?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just like ordinary algebraic operations have inverses, could we imagine the inverse of a set? Like $x\in\{x\}$ then maybe the inverse denoted $[|x|]$ would mean

$$\{\ [|x|]\ \}=x$$

Would this idea ever be useful?

Also we could define the cardinality of the inverse of a set as for example $$\operatorname{card}[|x|]=-1$$

Comment: You can have an inverse mapping of one set to another

Comment: [About negative cardinality](http://mathoverflow.net/a/136388/7206).

Comment: Cardinality -1? Seems as strange as $\pi-ie$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that doesn't really work. The *fundamental* property we want the notation $\{x\}$ to have is that
$$ \forall y: y\in\{x\} \iff y=x $$
If we can't preserve that, then whatever we get is not worthy of being notated $\{x\}$.

Now consider your specification
$$ \{ [x] \} = x $$
and let's see where that leads us if we take for example $x=\{0,1\}$.

$$ \{ [\{0,1\}] \} = \{0,1\} $$
So by definition of $\{x\}$ we have
$$ \forall y: y \in \{0,1\} \iff y = [\{0,1\}] $$
In particular by setting $y$ to $0$ and then $1$ we get
$$ 0 = [\{0,1\}] = 1 $$
so $0=1$. And even worse, this reasoning doesn't depend at all on what $0$ and $1$ are, so the consequences of having your inverse is that *it becomes impossible for a set to have two different elements*. Either something must prevent us from forming $\{0,1\}$, or everything is equal to everything else. And neither of these is a useful situation for doing mathematics in.

---

Of course you can have your $[x]$ if you accept that it will only work as specified in the special case that $x$ is a set with exactly one element. In that case $[x]$ will of course be that element. But that's not very interesting either.

We can say, for example,
$$ (\exists y: x=\{y\}) \implies x = \{ \bigcup x \} $$
where $\bigcup x$ is the set of all elements of elements of $x$, whose existence is what the set-theoretic Axiom of Union guarantees. So in that restricted sense, $\bigcup x$ can be viewed as the "inverse" of $x$ you're envisaging.

Comment: Very correct +1

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot to check how that new concepts would fit given the classic axioms of sets, very instructive indeed!

Comment: There is already an operation which returns the content of a singleton. $$\bigcup\{x\}=x$$

Comment: To Asaf: I saw that in your answer about the intuition for the axiom of choice, that's where my idea came from, but I thought to generalize the idea so that we could talk about negative cardinality thanks btw https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-are-the-axiom-of-choice-and-axiom-of-determinacy/52591#52591

Comment: @user202593: I am almost ashamed at how little I knew about choice back then. In these three and a half years I have learned so much more, and developed my intuition so much. In part because I answered so many questions online, and learned a lot from writing them. In any case, see the link I posted under your answer for my take on negative cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is used all the time in equivalence classes, e.g., $\mathbb{Z}_n$, where we send an integer $j$ to its equivalence class $[j]$, which is a set, a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$. This works for any set $S$ that is partitioned into subsets.

The key thing here is that $j \mapsto [j]$ is well defined.

Comment: I know that, I talked about conceiving a new object in addition to sets, like an anti-set. And also what about the cardinality?

Comment: I don't know where you're going there. Notions of negative cardinality don't on the face it appear very useful.