# Limit of derivative and derivability

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Assume that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both continuous real functions, and that, for $x \ne 0$, $f'(x) = g(x)$.

Is then $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = 0$, with $f'(0) = g(0)$?

Comment: With $x!=0$ i pressume you mean $x \neq 0$

Comment: So must g be defined at zero or not?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. By the MVT, we have
$$\dfrac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = f'(c(h))=g(c(h))$$
where $0<c(h)<h.$ Taking the limit as $h \to 0$ of both sides yields that $f$ is differentiable with $f'(0)=g(0).$

The reason why we are able to conclude that $\lim_{h \to 0} g(c(h))= g(0)$ is because $g$ is continuous, so  $\lim_{h \to 0} g(c(h))= g(\lim_{h \to 0} c(h))=g(0).$

Comment: I think it's worth elaborating on the last step when taking the limit $h \to 0$, because there, we need to make use of continuity of $g$ at $0$ (and that of course a similar argument works if $h<0$).

Comment: I think it would be perhaps more convincing to look at the limit $|{f(h)-f(0) \over h} - g(0)| $. The existence of a function $c$ would need to be established and is unnecessary.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Done

Comment: It is certainly true that for any $h$ there is some $\eta_h \in (0,h)$ such that the quotient above equals $g(\eta_h)$, but there are some logical steps needed to demonstrate that we can define a function $c(h) = g(\eta_h)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Hmm what are the extra logical steps?

Comment: Well, not quite axiom of choice, but more argument that is necessary, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1051775/27978 for example. Just stick with the existence of $\eta_h$ ofr simplicity.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the link!