# Continuous is sequentially continuous

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice

Is it possible to prove

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous everywhere iff it is sequentially continuous everywhere

**without** the axiom of choice?

Comment: Yes, see Brian M. Scott's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126010/continuity-and-the-axiom-of-choice/126012#126012).