# Is the axiom of countable choice needed for the proof of this special case of equivalence of limit definitions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, axiom-of-choice, epsilon-delta

[In this link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Function_by_Convergent_Sequences), a proof of the equivalence between the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition and the one with the convergent sequences is given.

I'm interested in the proof of this theorem simply for the metric space $(\Bbb R, |x-y|)$, and I was wondering if the axiom of countable choice was really needed in the sufficient condition part.

If there's a different proof of the general theorem which avoids this axiom, it would be very nice.

Comment: To sum up the two answers in the duplicate: If you are talking about continuity at a single point, yes; if you're talking about continuity everywhere, no.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Could you link the dupe?

Comment: @Eric: It's on the banner on the top of the question...

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I see no banner.  (Also, SE seems *very* laggy today (here).)

Comment: @EricTowers Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126010/continuity-and-the-axiom-of-choice .

Btw, the banner looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/i6p2kaf.png