# Proof of equivalence of continuity without using proof by contraposition

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Let $(X, d)$ and $(X^\prime, d^\prime)$ be metric spaces and $f: (X, d) \to (X^\prime, d^\prime)$ be a function. Consider the following (equivalent) definitions of continuity at $x \in X$:

- (P1): $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \hspace{0.5em} \text{s.t.} \hspace{0.5em} \forall x^\prime \in X, d(x^\prime, x) < \delta \implies d^\prime(f(x^\prime), f(x)) < \epsilon$
- (P2): $\forall \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty (\subseteq X), \ x_n \to x \implies f(x_n) \to f(x)$

The proof of $\text{(P1)} \implies \text{(P2)}$  is easy and straightforward. The proof of $\text{(P2)} \implies \text{(P1)}$ is also easy if we show $\lnot \text{(P1)} \implies \lnot \text{(P2)}$.

However I do not come up with nor see the direct (not using the contrapositive relation) proof $\text{(P2)} \implies \text{(P1)}$. Does anyone know it?

P.S.

@Tom Collinge: Thnak you for your comment. I need to clarify my question: **Is there a way to prove $\text{(P2)} \implies \text{(P1)}$ without assuming $\lnot \text{(P1)}$?**. Although proof by contrapositive and proof by contradiction are not equivalent in general, I think steps of the two proofs are almost same in this question.

@mechanodroid and @LoveTooNap29: Thank you for helpful comments! I saw Brian M. Scott's answer for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126010/continuity-and-the-axiom-of-choice) and still have following unclear points

- (minor) when we prove $\text{[sequentially continuous]} \implies \text{[$\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuous]}$, we need the axiom of countable choice (CC), **whether using proof by contrapositive or not** (contrapositive case is mentioned in the question).
- (major) I think Brian M. Scott's answer uses a kind of $\lnot \text{(P1)} \implies \lnot \text{(P2)}$ discussion in the proof of his Claim:

  > If $f$ is sequentially continuous at $x$ (P2), then $f \upharpoonright (\mathbb{Q} \cup \{x\})$ is $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuous at $x$ (P1)

Comment: Not that this answers your question but: In my mind, this question is simply more evidence for the fact that we should be comfortable with using contrapositives. That logical tool exists to make proofs easier, as it has done here.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126010/144766) for a proof when $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid  I'm sorry I don't understand which answer you refer to...

Comment: I have just recently read that directly proving sequential continuity implies the standard $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuity requires using the weak axiom of choice, and i believe the post linked by mechanodroid is a discussion/example of this.

Comment: @myuuuuun Exactly what LoveTooNap29 says. Have a look at Brian M. Scott's answer in the linked question.

Comment: This is a more general result that in a first countable topological space continuity  is equivalent to sequential continuity. When I checked my notes I see that in this context sequential continuity implies continuity is proved by contradiction - hope this helps.