# Is it enough to take the limit on increasing sequences that go to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $\ell\in\mathbb R$, and assume that, for every **increasing** sequence $(\omega_n)\in\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\omega_n= \infty$, one has $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\omega_n) = \ell$. Is it necessarily true then, that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \ell$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: Well, if the limit is not $\ell$  then for some positive $\epsilon$ it must be the case that there are arbitrarily large values $x_n$ for which $|f(x_n)-\ell|>\epsilon$.  use that.

Comment: @lulu I see, in that case one can construct an increasing sequence $(x_n)$ that is unbounded (and thus, will go to infinity) and satisfies $|f(x_n) - \ell| > \epsilon$ for all $n$... Thank you!

Comment: Yep, that's precisely the idea.

Comment: If you reject ${\bf CC}(\Bbb R)$, the axiom of countable choice for subsets of $\mathbb R$, this can be false. [This answer by Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126012/177399) shows the idea.