# Where do I use finiteness in this proof of: In ZF, the compactness theorem implies the Axiom of Choice for collections of finite sets?

Tags: induction, set-theory, compactness, axiom-of-choice, transfinite-induction

Work in ZF, and assume the compactness theorem. Let $\mathsf{AC}^\text{fin}$ be the sentence "every collection of ***finite*** non-empty sets has a choice function".

UPDATE: Thank you to the helpful answerers. My proof below is invalid, and has been struck through to avoid confusing future generations of questioneers and maths students.

<del>Here is my proof sketch of $\mathsf{Compactness} \vdash \mathsf{AC}^\text{fin}$: let $\phi_n$ be the sentence "every non-empty collection of $n$ finite sets has a choice function", for each $n\in\omega$. By induction, we show this holds for arbitrarily large finite collections of $\phi_n$s: if $n=0$, then $\varnothing$ is our choice function; if $n=k+1$ and the claim holds for $k$, then we can partition our collection into a $k$-size family and a singleton family, each of which have choice functions. Now we invoke compactness to extend it to the set of all $\phi_n$.</del>

I'm not seeing where we used the finiteness of the individual sets, since each step seems to hold irregardless.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402543/is-the-compactness-theorem-from-mathematical-logic-equivalent-to-the-axiom-of), though it names both "compactness" and "axiom of choice", seems not to be relevant.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657972/does-the-axiom-of-choice-have-any-use-for-finite-sets), [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132717/do-we-need-the-axiom-of-choice-for-finite-sets?rq=1), and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85153/how-do-i-choose-an-element-from-a-non-empty-set) seem to be more about the act of choosing itself.

Comment: The collections aren’t finite. The sets are finite. You’ve prove a finite collection of finite sets has a choice function.

Comment: Whoops, I've added "non-empty" to the statement.

Comment: Would I instead need to induct over all of $ON$? If so, then I suppose we might need the finiteness condition at limit stages.

Comment: Here's my new idea: we could let $\Phi$ be the set of all $\phi_n$s for $n\in ON$, take an arbitrary finite subset $F$ of $\Phi$, and then induct on the maximal index of the $\phi_n$s in $F$, which exists because $F$ is finite and wellordered.

Comment: What is $ON?$ Your question is sparse of notation.

Comment: Sorry, the class of ordinals. But please disregard my above comments, thanks to Asaf's wonderful answer below.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: ON or ORD are fairly standard set theoretic notations for the class of ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction won't do you any good, because at the end of the day, nobody said anything about the family of finite sets being well-orderable. Nor would "choose from $n$ sets at once" is going to do you any good.

The "standard" approach is to first prove from compactness that every set can be linearly ordered, and then given a family of finite sets, $\cal A$, we linearly order $\bigcup\cal A$ and then each of these finite sets has a minimum which we can choose.

But, this is a fun exercise. So, how do we apply compactness directly? Well, let $\cal L$ be the language in which we have a predicate for each $A\in\cal A$ and a constant $c_a$ for each $a\in\bigcup\cal A$; and next we add axioms that state:

1. $c_a\in A$ if and only if $a\in A$, for any $a\in\bigcup\cal A$ and $A\in\cal A$;
2. The predicate $A$ has exactly $|A|$ elements, for any $A\in\cal A$; and
3. $c_a\neq c_b$ for any pair of distinct $a,b\in\bigcup\cal A$.

Now, add a constant $c_A$ for each $A\in\cal A$ and an axiom stating that $c_A\in A$. This expanded theory is finitely satisfiable, so by compactness it is satisfiable. But since $A$ have exactly $n$ elements, we did not add any new elements to the predicate, so $c_A$ must be equal to some $c_a$ for $a\in A$, for any $A\in\cal A$. And this defines our choice function.

Here we see why we can only apply this logic to families of finite sets. If $A$ was not finite, we can only state, using first-order logic, that it is not finite. So compactness arguments may add "non-standard" elements to our sets $A$, which mean that we cannot use the $c_A$ constants to define an actual choice function.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive response — let me just make sure I understand the construction. Is the intuition behind each $c_a$ to "index" the elements of $\bigcup \mathcal A$ with the set $A$ that they came from? Then, we use axiom (2) with the pigeonhole principle to identify $c_A = c_A$?

Comment: Also, in response to your last paragraph, does this mean we couldn't state axiom (2) without finiteness?

Comment: To your first question, yes. To the second, I'm not quite sure where pigeonhole principle comes into play, the point in axiom (2) is ensuring that we can write $\forall x(x\in A\leftrightarrow\bigvee_{a\in A}x=c_a)$ as a first-order sentence, which then ensures that compactness doesn't add "artificial elements" to the predicate $A$. Which is also exactly where we really rely on the finiteness of the sets.

Comment: Okay, that clears things up. I'd erroneously thought we were using pigeonhole to make $c_A$ hit one of the $c_a$s.

Comment: I mean, you can make the argument that the function $i\mapsto c_i$ defined from $A\cup\{A\}$ into $A$ cannot be injective, which does rely on the pigeonhole principle. But it seems like an incredibly cumbersome way to do that. Also, I forgot to add the axioms that the $c_a$s are distinct for different $a$s. I fixed that now.