# Using Zorn's Lemma, for a function $f: X \to Y$, show that the poset of partial sections of $f$, $((A, u), ≤)$, is non-empty.

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I was reading the book Sets, Models and Proofs and I'm now stuck at the part where they prove that Zorn's Lemma implies AC. In particular, this part:

"Proof.
We assume that Zorn’s Lemma is true.
Suppose given a surjective function $f : X → Y$. A partial section of $f$ is a pair
$(A, u)$ where $A$ is a subset of $Y$ and $u : A → X$ a function such that $f (u(y)) = y$ for
each $y ∈ A$. Given two such partial sections $(A, u)$ and $(B, v)$, put $(A, u) ≤ (B, v)$
iff $A ⊆ B $ and u is the restriction of v to A. Let P be the set of partial sections (A, u)
of f ; then with the relation ≤, P is a poset, as is easy to see.

P is nonempty; this is left to you. . ."

What I'm confused about is this: Doesn't the existence of (A, u) require the Axiom of Choice? Because you have to **choose** an u for which f(u(y)) = y. For each y ∈ A, you have to pick an u(y) = x. I honestly don't see how I can prove that P is nonempty without using the Axiom of Choice or by using Zorn's Lemma, which is defined in the book as:

"Definition 1.3.4
Zorn’s Lemma is the following assertion: if (P , ≤) is a poset with
the property that every chain in P has an upper bound in P, then P has a maximal
element.
Note that if P satisfies the hypothesis of Zorn’s Lemma, then P is nonempty. This
is so because the empty subset of P is always a chain. However, checking that every
chain has an upper bound in P usually involves checking this for the empty chain
separately; that is, checking that P is nonempty."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
For anyone that comes here after me, [Do We Need the Axiom of Choice for Finite Sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132717/do-we-need-the-axiom-of-choice-for-finite-sets) was also really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax! As written your post is unreadable. Putting $ signs in between math formulas may help.

Comment: Let $a\in X$ and $b=f(a)$. Then $(A,u)\in P$ if $A=\{b\}$ and $u(b)=a$. This shows that $P\neq\varnothing$ and we did not use AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the proof, the author is just saying what means that a pair $(A, u)$ is a partial section of $f$, it doesn't say anything about if such a pair exists for any given $A\subseteq Y$, the important thing is that the set of ALL partial sections of $f$ is not empty, but this is easy to check, just take any $y\in Y$, since $f$ is surjective there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)= y$ and if you define $u : \{y\} \rightarrow X$ as $u(y):=x$ then the pair $(\{y\}, u)$ is a partial section of $f$.

Comment: But doesn't this mean you still just **choose** an _x_ so that $f(x) = y$ for any $( {y} , u)$ ? Because for every $y∈Y$ there might be multiple _x_ for which $f(x) = y$.

Comment: @bowieschoonderbeek It is no problem to make  a **single choice** or **finitely many choices**. The axiom of choice is only needed if we want to make infinitely many choices. Here you choose a single $y \in Y$ and then a single $x \in f^{-1}(y)$.